# Message is not re updating

Tags: c#

I have 2 kind of "Description" for class "People",

1. Having data with Message:, Priority: and Tag:
2. Having data without these

   ```
   List<People> lstPeople = new List<People>
   {
       new People { Message = "[1y] Message: test messg1 Priority: top Tag: t1" },
       new People { Message = "without Message, Priority and Tag desc" }
   };
   var data = lstPeople;
   ```

I would like to extract data after "Message:", "Priority:" and "Tag:" and re-update of each entity of "People" class "Message", "Priority" and "Tag".

Below code does update for "Priority" and "Tag" but not for "Message". What could be the reason?

```
    public class People
{
    const string ALERT_DESC_MARKER = "Message:";
    const string PRIORITY_MARKER = "Priority:";
    const string TAG_MARKER = "Tag:";
    private string _description;
    private string _tag;
    private string _priority;
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            if (_description.Contains(ALERT_DESC_MARKER) && _description.Contains(PRIORITY_MARKER))
                return _description ?? GetTextPart(_description, ALERT_DESC_MARKER, PRIORITY_MARKER).Trim();
            else
                return _description;
        }
        set
        {
            _description = value;
        }
    }

    public string Priority
    {
        get
        {
            if (_description.Contains(PRIORITY_MARKER) && _description.Contains(TAG_MARKER))
                return _priority = GetTextPart(_description, PRIORITY_MARKER, TAG_MARKER).Trim();
            else
                return _priority;
        }
        set
        {
            _priority = value;
        }
    }

    public string Tag
    {
        get
        {
            if (_description.Contains(TAG_MARKER))
                return _tag = GetTextPart(_description, TAG_MARKER, null).Trim();
            else
                return _tag;
        }
        set
        {
            _tag = value;
        }
    }

    private string GetTextPart(string text, string before, string after)
    {
        string result = null;
        int posBefore = text.IndexOf(before);

        if (after != null)
        {
            int posAfter = text.IndexOf(after);
            result = text.Remove(posAfter).Substring(posBefore + before.Length).TrimEnd();
        }
        else
            result = text.Substring(posBefore + before.Length);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you like to do... where descriptuon does not update?

Comment: Sorry, not related, but I sensed something wrong with the logic, because it doesn't look uniform. Priority getter has if condition to check Desc_Marker, but ignores it and get the text using TagMarker. Also getter sets _priority to a new value (while Message getter does not set to new value).

Comment: @kurakura88, the People class has been updated now

Comment: @Tester, question heading is updated and I want to update Message from "[1y] Message: test messg1 Priority: top Tag: t1"   to  "test messg1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the getter of `Message`.
As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms173224.aspx) says:

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

So in your case you always return the entire `string` if `_description` is not `null`. Instead you need to return `GetTextPart` if this condition (_decription != null) is met. Like this:

```
if (_description.Contains(ALERT_DESC_MARKER) && _description.Contains(PRIORITY_MARKER))
    return _description != null ? GetTextPart(_description, ALERT_DESC_MARKER, PRIORITY_MARKER).Trim() : _description;
```

**EDIT:**

Here is your test example:

```
List<People> lstPeople = new List<People>
{
    new People { Message = "[1y] Message: test messg1 Priority: top Tag: t1" },
    new People { Message = "without Message, Priority and Tag desc" }
};
var data = lstPeople;


foreach (var item in lstPeople)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Message);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Priority);
    Console.WriteLine(item.Tag);
}
```

Output first Item:

> test messg1
>
> top
>
> t1

Output second Item:

> without Message, Priority and Tag desc

in the second item `Priority` and `Tag` are null.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the `Message` getter. The rest of the code that I used to test is identical to the one that you posted. The commented out part is your old/posted version

```
public string Message
{
    get
    {
        if (_description.Contains(ALERT_DESC_MARKER) && _description.Contains(PRIORITY_MARKER))
            return _description != null ? GetTextPart(_description, ALERT_DESC_MARKER, PRIORITY_MARKER).Trim(): _description;

        //if (_description.Contains(ALERT_DESC_MARKER) && _description.Contains(PRIORITY_MARKER))
        //    return _description ?? GetTextPart(_description, ALERT_DESC_MARKER, PRIORITY_MARKER).Trim();
        else
            return _description;
    }
    set
    {
        _description = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: by above I am getting Message string "test messg1", but Priority and Tag are then null

Comment: how do you test it? I get only in the second item in your `lstPeople` `List` `null` values for `Priority` and `Tag`. Check my edit please

Comment: could you please post the "People" class or at least "Message" getter/setter? I m getting error

Comment: Is this Message getter correct?   get
            {
                if (_description.Contains(ALERT_DESC_MARKER) && _description.Contains(PRIORITY_MARKER))
                {
                    if (_description != null)
                        return GetTextPart(_description, ALERT_DESC_MARKER, PRIORITY_MARKER).Trim();
                    else
                        return _description;
                }
                else
                    return _description;

            }

Comment: I posted it, did you change something else in your code? the code from your comment works also like a charm

Comment: cool, but now I am curious, how did you get the `null` values ??

Comment: are you asking for 2nd item in People's List? which "null" you are asking?

Comment: I am asking about your first comment: "by above I am getting Message string "test messg1", but Priority and Tag are then null"

Comment: for 2nd line item of People's List, I am fine with Priority and Tag values as "null" :)

Comment: Ok, the first comment.... no it's fine now, I am getting Message = "test messg1", Priority = "top" and Tag = "t1" for first line item